# How to get list of people those are more than 40 year old in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am calculating age of the people in Codeigniter by their Date of Birth. I want to Separate the people where age is more than 40 years. I have used the simple condition `if($age>40){my code block}` but it does not work for those whose age is `40 years and  month>0 or you may say 40 years and 0 month and days>0`
is their any built-in function in CodeIgniter for this purpose or any solution..?
thanks in advance...

Comment: Well one solution you got right there in your own question already ... write code that checks those additional conditions as alternatives then?

Comment: sure but I'll have to write more than one condition.

Comment: And you say that as if it was an actual problem/issue, because ...?

Comment: Can you not use `$age >= 40`?

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on where you get the age data from.
Is it stored as 40 years, 2 months or is that a calculation made from a birth date?
Did you try if ($age >= 40) ?

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution that works for me if age is 40 and month is greater than 0 or day is greater than 0.

```
if ($ageyear > 40 || ($ageyear == 40 && ($agemonth > 0 || $agedays > 0))) {
$isOverAge = "Over age";
}
```